# How can i use MobilePush in different BUs?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilepush

My client has 2 BUs on their Marketing Cloud account, we have another company integrating their mobile app with Marketing Cloud for us and we managed to set up and test MobilePush on the master BU. However, they'll also need to use MobilePush on a different BU, and i have no idea how to proceed with this scenario, since the only thing i can think about as a solution is to build several different Android/IOS apps and also different MobilePush apps, but that just doesn't make sense to me. What's the actual solution for using MobilePush with different BUs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please describe the use-case you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi. So, my client is quite big, they have a few divisions within the company. Right now they have a child BU that is for a very specific purpose (for people who have the company's credit card). In the future, they plan to have several other BUs, each for a specific purpose. But they only have one mobile app for each platform, and they are wondering if they can use the same Android/IOS apps for different BUs for sending Push notifications.

Answer (score 1):

The customer should disable push in the original BU and upon success re-initialize the SDK in the new BU (ref. https://gist.github.com/sfmc-mobilepushsdk/85c0b2e7ea13b47d9322166406baddec). If they wish to migrate the data for Tags, Attributes and Contact Key they would need to gather that data and re-apply it in the new BU (ref. https://gist.github.com/sfmc-mobilepushsdk/f7e04c905bd97656496b1bc0a8ec7c30).

```
/*
    1. Get an instance of the SDK
    2. Gather the data you wish to transfer
    3. Register a Registration Listener
    4. Disable Push (opt the device out)
    5. Re-init the SDK with the new BU credentials
    6. Set the values you previously gathered
 */
private fun migrateBU() {
  MarketingCloudSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->

    // Gather the data from the existing BU that you want to migrate
    var attributes: Map<String, String>
    var tags: Set<String>
    var contactKey: String?

    with(sdk.registrationManager) {
      attributes = this.attributes
      tags = this.tags
      contactKey = this.contactKey
    }

    // Register a registration listener which will be called upon a successful registration
    sdk.registrationManager.registerForRegistrationEvents {

      // Re-initialize the SDK with new BU credentials
      MarketingCloudSdk.init(context, MarketingCloudConfig.builder().apply {
        setApplicationId("{new BU application id}")
        setAccessToken("{new BU access token}")
        setMarketingCloudServerUrl("{new BU Marketing Cloud server URL}")
        // Other configuration values as required -- nothing will be carried over from previous configurations
      }.build(context)) {
        when (it.status) {
          InitializationStatus.Status.SUCCESS -> {
            setDataInNewBU(attributes, tags, contactKey)
          }
          else -> {
            // Handle Failure
          }
        }
      }
    }
    // Disable Push which will trigger a Registration
    sdk.pushMessageManager.disablePush()
  }
}

private fun setDataInNewBU(attributes: Map<String, String>, tags: Set<String>, contactKey: String?) {
  MarketingCloudSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
    sdk.registrationManager.edit().apply {
      attributes.forEach {
        setAttribute(it.key, it.value)
      }
      addTags(tags)
      contactKey?.let {
        setContactKey(it)
      }
      commit()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this works well - however, we're having trouble with the opens tracking coming back to the correct BU, they are only going back to the most recently registered BU.  Is there any solution to this?

Comment: No.  A user should not be registered in 2 BUs simultaneously.  This is not a supported use-case.

Comment: Thanks Bill, maybe just a bit more clarification is needed on my side:  we have connected up 2 BU's to the same app, and are able to register and send push notifications successfully.  The only thing that's missing is having the opens tracking going to both BUs (currently only going back to the most recently registered BU).  We aren't sending to the same user in both BUs, they are different users.

Comment: This will eventually break and there currently is no way to accomplish what you want.  The push token can change and would get out of sync.  Any consumer/device attributes that change will get out of sync.